# Area included in the graph of various functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

I've some problems recognizing which one is the area between various function. In this case i need to calculate the area between 3 lines and a curve, exactly between:

$x+3,x^2-9,x=5 ,x=0$

I can't understand the graphs:

[image]

Which one is the area i need? It seems like the curve pass in the middle of the area, so it's correct taking the area from $x=0$ to the curve?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. This question is nonsense. The only finite areas in the diagram are:

- The area between the curve and the line $y=x+3$. This is is divided in two parts (also finite) by the line $x=0$. But the line $x=3$ is irrelevant.
- The area at the top right of your picture, above $y=x+3$, to the left of $x=5$, and to the right of $y=x^2+9$. But the line $x=0$ is irrelevant.

Conceivably the question is intended to ask for a combination of two of these areas, but basically it is nonsensical and you should complain.